# Image is not loaded in product detailed page only magento 2.3

Tags: url, image

I have added the image in admin panel backend image show homepage,category page show but product detailed  page image is not shown certain url link.i have shared.

URL:https://sarikart.com/3003maroon-exclusive-handloom-saree-collection.html

Comment: it may cache image issue can you try image resize command once?

Answer (score 0):

Two things you can try and have worked for me in the past:

- php bin/magento indexer:reindex
- php bin/magento cache:clean
- php bin/magento cache:flush

If this does not work please check on your admin panel if the image is assigned to the roles (Base, Small and Thumbnail) in the store view you are using.

Any help let me know !